# What are the rules to avoid an INVALID REQUEST on GOOGLE API DIstance matrix call?

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

Really like the Google DistanceMatrix API functionality, but I occasional get an INVALID REQUEST that I just can't explain. I've verified the FROM and TO addresses are correct in MAPS.GOOGLE.COM and try to ensure all special characters are addressed.

Here is an example of such a call (API Key removed)

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=5085+Business+Center+Dr.+#102%2CFairfield%2CCA+94533&destinations=5142+MONO+CT%2CFAIRFIELD%2CCA+94534&key=(api_key)

But rather than just address this particular call, is there a checklist or set of rules for debugging this and future INVALID REQUESTS?

Note to Google: Would be nice if INVALID REQUEST included something like a reason code (that could be looked up) and an indicator which parm was the one being flagged.

Thanks to all! You do amazing work here.

Comment: I don't get INVALID_REQUEST with the posted URL. Is it sporadic/not consistent?

Comment: Wow. that is interesting, @geocodezip. Not sure what to make of it. In answer to your question, the vast majority of the calls work fine, and the ones that get an INVALID REQUEST fail consistently. If others find it works, I'll probably pull the question just to ponder it further. Thanks!'

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, indeed the request looks fine.
this is what I got as response:

```
{
destination_addresses: [
"5142 Mono Ct, Fairfield, CA 94534, USA"
],
origin_addresses: [
"5085 Business Center Dr #102, Fairfield, CA 94534, USA"
],
rows: [
{
elements: [
{
distance: {
text: "1.0 mi",
value: 1668
},
duration: {
text: "4 mins",
value: 212
},
status: "OK"
}
]
}
],
status: "OK"
}
```

Comment: Thanks betofarina. So the URL is good. Leaves me with a bit of a mystery. I think I'll close this as both you and geocodezip advanced enough knowledge here I need to step back and review

Answer (score 0):

I think you should [URL-encode](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) your address strings.

For example, I can see a `#` symbol in your example that should be replaced with the `%23` in encoded form. This symbol has a special meaning in URL, so it can break your request and lead to `INVALID REQUEST` status.

I would expect the following request after complete encoding:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=5085%20Business%20Center%20Dr.%20%23102%2C%20Fairfield%2C%20CA%2094533&destinations=5142%20MONO%20CT%2C%20FAIRFIELD%2C%20CA%2094534&units=imperial&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Hope this helps!