# Google Nearby Places API Call - Invalid Request

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I am using Python Requests to get the JSON data from google API. I keep getting invalid requests when my URL is like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=27.950575,-82.457176&key=GOOGLE_KEY

Here is the JSON Output:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Comment: related question: [What are the rules to avoid an INVALID REQUEST on GOOGLE API DIstance matrix call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48231873/what-are-the-rules-to-avoid-an-invalid-request-on-google-api-distance-matrix-cal)

Answer (score 0):

The comma should not be there. It should be %2C instead. Also, refining the search to restaurants, for instance, will return results. Scroll down to the Python code here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#python

I just copied the url there and changed it to be like this in my python:

```
formatted_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location='+str(lat)+'%2C'+str(lon)+'&radius=1500&type=restaurant&key='+google_key
```

and this returned positive results!